# Unable to pip install library with a specific version but able to do it without version

Tags: python, pip, version

I tried to install numpy version 1.13.3 . I did `pip install numpy==1.13.3` and it ran unsuccessfully.

```
Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0dci9ehe\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0dci9ehe\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dlf9c_63\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Include\numpy'
```

I am using python 3.8.6. It is unsucesfull within any version <= 1.17 but succesfull with version 1.18 and 1.19 . I have also tried with others libraries like pandas==0.19.2 and it the same error occurs.

I do not really understand the error message and I suppose the problem is coming from my AppData folder any better understanding is welcome.

Comment: Are you running within a virtual environment ? i not it may solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

File -> Settings -> nameOfProject -> Project Interpreter

then in the project interpreter it should show the current version you have in the left of the table and the latest version you can update it to on the right.  Press on the package (in your case numpy) so the line across it goes blue then press the upgrade arrow to the right of the box (underneath the + and -) and it should update that way instead of manually.